# Ho do I Parse XML using Google Apps Script and loop through all elements

Tags: javascript, xml, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is my first time working with XML and I am not that techy but trying to get to understand programming to make my work easier. I am using Google App script and finding it a challenge in passing XML data that I get via API.

I need to get this data so that I can set the specific values to Google sheets using google app script.

I am not sure how to iterate/loop through elements to get everyone's data and then set it to google sheet.

And here is the code I have worked on so far. When I log to say the first name, I only get one name instead of about 50 names in the system. Any help here will highly be appreciated.

```
ak ='key'
start = '2019-01-01'
end = '2019-12-31'

function getData() { 

 var options = {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ak
    }
};  
var url = 'https://data.purelyhr.com/daily?ak='+ ak + '&sDate=' + start + '&eDate=' + end + '&TimeOffTypeName';
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
var document = XmlService.parse(response);
var root = document.getRootElement();


//set variables to data from PurelyHR

var TimeOffDate = root.getChild('Request').getChild('TimeOffDate').getText();
var TimeOffDayOfWeek = root.getChild('Request').getChild('TimeOffDayOfWeek').getText();
var TimeStart = root.getChild('Request').getChild('TimeStart').getText();
var TimeEnd = root.getChild('Request').getChild('TimeEnd').getText();
var TimeOffHours = root.getChild('Request').getChild('TimeOffHours').getText();
var TimeOffTypeName = root.getChild('Request').getChild('TimeOffTypeName').getText();
var LoginID= root.getChild('Request').getChild('LoginID').getText();
var Firstname = root.getChild('Request').getChild('Firstname').getText();
var Lastname = root.getChild('Request').getChild('Lastname').getText();
var UserCategory = root.getChild('Request').getChild('UserCategory').getText();
var SubmittedDate = root.getChild('Request').getChild('SubmittedDate').getText();
var Deducted = root.getChild('Request').getChild('Deducted').getText();
var Comment = root.getChild('Request').getChild('Comment').getText();


//populate the sheet with variable data


Logger.log(response)
}
```

Sample response

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<DataService>
    <Request ID="1253" Status="Approved">
        <TimeOffDate>2020-02-07</TimeOffDate>
        <TimeOffDayOfWeek>Friday</TimeOffDayOfWeek>
        <TimeStart></TimeStart>
        <TimeEnd></TimeEnd>
        <TimeOffHours>8.000</TimeOffHours>
        <TimeOffTypeName>Annual Vacation</TimeOffTypeName>
        <LoginID>testuser</LoginID>
        <Firstname>test</Firstname>
        <Lastname>user</Lastname>
        <UserCategory></UserCategory>
        <SubmittedDate>2019-10-03</SubmittedDate>
        <Deducted>Yes</Deducted>
        <Comment>
            <![CDATA[* time-off request created by administrator]]>
        </Comment>
    </Request>
    <Request ID="126292" Status="Approved">
        <TimeOffDate>2020-02-07</TimeOffDate>
        <TimeOffDayOfWeek>Friday</TimeOffDayOfWeek>
        <TimeStart></TimeStart>
        <TimeEnd></TimeEnd>
        <TimeOffHours>8.000</TimeOffHours>
        <TimeOffTypeName>Annual Vacation</TimeOffTypeName>
        <LoginID>usertwo</LoginID>
        <Firstname>user</Firstname>
        <Lastname>two</Lastname>
        <UserCategory></UserCategory>
        <SubmittedDate>2019-10-15</SubmittedDate>
        <Deducted>Yes</Deducted>
        <Comment>
            <![CDATA[Neil (as my mentor)]]>
        </Comment>
    </Request>
```

Comment: I think that when the sample values of `response` in your script is provided as the text values, it will help users think of the solution. Of course, please remove your personal information. And also, can you provide the output values you expect?

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for taking the time to look at the code. I have edited it to include a sample response. The expected output data that I need should be all the child objects in the response (I.e TimeOffDate, LoginID e.t.c). I hope this helps to clarify?

Comment: You've provided screenshots right now, but if someone would want to help you he needs to manually type the XML out. If you can provide this as text in your question, we can simply copy it over and start testing code.

Comment: @Casper, thanks for the recommendation. The question is now edited.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed that your issue has already been resolved. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the problem is that you have multiple `<Request>` elements, but your code is only looking at one of them. This is because you're using [`getChild()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/element#getChild(String)), which will only provide the *first* element with the given name.

I can't fully test that this works because you haven't provided the XML text, but you should instead use the [`getChildren()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/element#getChildren(String)) method to get all of the Request elements. Then you can loop through that.

```
function getData() {
  var options = {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ak
    }
  };
  var url = 'https://data.purelyhr.com/daily?ak=' + ak + '&sDate=' + start + '&eDate=' + end + '&TimeOffTypeName';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var document = XmlService.parse(response);
  var root = document.getRootElement();

  //set variables to data from PurelyHR
  var requestElements = root.getChildren('Request'); // Get all <Request> elements
  var requestObjects = []; // Request objects for logging / eventual printing
  for (var i = 0; i < requestElements.length; i++) {
    var request = requestElements[i]; // A single <Request> element

    // Add to requestObjects array
    requestObjects.push({
      TimeOffDate: request.getChild('TimeOffDate').getText(),
      TimeOffDayOfWeek: request.getChild('TimeOffDayOfWeek').getText(),
      TimeStart: request.getChild('TimeStart').getText(),
      TimeEnd: request.getChild('TimeEnd').getText(),
      TimeOffHours: request.getChild('TimeOffHours').getText(),
      TimeOffTypeName: request.getChild('TimeOffTypeName').getText(),
      LoginID: request.getChild('LoginID').getText(),
      Firstname: request.getChild('Firstname').getText(),
      Lastname: request.getChild('Lastname').getText(),
      UserCategory: request.getChild('UserCategory').getText(),
      SubmittedDate: request.getChild('SubmittedDate').getText(),
      Deducted: request.getChild('Deducted').getText(),
      Comment: request.getChild('Comment').getText()
    });
  }

  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(requestObjects));
}
```

Since I don't know how you're printing, I created an array of request objects and logged that in the sample above. I hope this made sense, but please let me know if you have any questions or if I'm completely off with my response.

Comment: Thanks, Diego, This makes a lot of sense.  From this solution, I will be able to set the values in a google sheet.

Comment: Hey Diego, just a quick one. I would like to get the parent data also in the XML **<Request ID="126292" Status=" Approved">**, these are not children. How do I push these to my array

Comment: @Just You mean the  ID and Status values?

Comment: Yes, Diego,  That is exactly what I mean

Comment: @Just Use [getAttribute()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/element#getattributename)... e.g. `request.getAttribute("ID")`

Comment: I have added that line inside the requestObjects.push, but I keep getting **SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**, could I be doing something wrong ?

Comment: @Just An error usually means that you're doing something wrong :) More details will be needed to help you figure it out, so I recommend posting a new question.

Comment: I have posted it as another question. Thanks